# Python 3 project not giving me the result i am looking for

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python through Codecademy, and I have run into a weird result in the  "Sal's shipping" project.

What I am trying make python do, is tell me what shipping method is the cheapest. Here is a code sample:

```
print(cost_ground_shipping(4.8))
print(cheapest_shipping(4.8))
```

This gives me:

```
34.4
Premium shipping is the cheapest at $125
```

The problem here is, that premium shipping obviously is not cheaper at 125 dollars, as ground shipping is 34.4 dollars.

I am sorry that the code is a mess. In the tutorial video the guy uses specific techniques, that have not been covered in the course, which annoyed me, so I ignored it, as I did not want to completely rewrite my code.

Any answers are appreciated :)

Here is the full code:

```
def cost_ground_shipping(weight):
  if weight <= 2:
    return weight * 1.5 + 20
  elif 6 >= weight:
    return weight * 3. + 20
  elif 10 >= weight:
    return weight * 4. + 20
  else:
    return weight * 4.75 + 20

cost_premium_shipping = 125

def cost_drone_shipping(weight):
  if weight <= 2:
    return weight * 4.5
  if 6 >= weight > 2:
    return weight * 9.
  if 10 >= weight > 6:
    return weight * 12.
  if weight > 10:
    return weight * 14.25 + 20

def cheapest_shipping(weight):
  if str(cost_ground_shipping(weight)) < str(cost_premium_shipping) and str(cost_ground_shipping(weight)) < str(cost_drone_shipping(weight)):
    return "Ground shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_ground_shipping(weight))
  if str(cost_premium_shipping) < str(cost_ground_shipping(weight)) and str(cost_premium_shipping) < str(cost_drone_shipping(weight)):
    return "Premium shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_premium_shipping)
  if str(cost_drone_shipping(weight)) < str(cost_ground_shipping(weight)) and str(cost_drone_shipping(weight)) < str(cost_premium_shipping):
    return "Drone shipping is the cheapest at $" + str(cost_drone_shipping(weight))

print(cost_ground_shipping(4.8))
print(cheapest_shipping(4.8))
```

Comment: Why on earth are you converting the shipping costs to strings before you compare them?

Comment: removing the 'str' in your last function gives the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan, welcome to Stack Overflow.
In Python, similar to most programming languages, strings are also comparable and ordered (i.e the inequality operators have meaning).

```
def cheapest_shipping(weight):
  if str(cost_ground_shipping(weight)) < str(cost_premium_shipping)..
  ..
  if str(cost_premium_shipping) < str(cost_ground_shipping(weight))
```

You are inadvertently performing string comparisons here, i.e you are comparing the STRING "34.4" with "125". The computer interprets strings as sequence of characters and compares the ASCII codes of the characters sequentially. Since "1" has an ASCII code of 49 and "3" has the ASCII code 51, "1" is lesser than "3", and consequently "125" < "34.4". This is why you get the "wrong" answer.

Omit the str conversion functions when you want to compare numbers. Keep the str functions when you want to PRINT numbers.