# Sal's Shipping problem in the Python 3 module of Codecademy

Tags: python

I'm new to stackoverflow and I originally posted this as a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109737/python-3-project-not-giving-me-the-result-i-am-looking-for/56687662#56687662) because it was related but it was suggested I make it a new post so here it is:

My attempt to solve the lesson looks similar to OP's but a cursory look has given me some ideas to fix it which I want to try before posing here. However, I looked at the help video and they solve the problem by beginning their code with

```
def print_cheapest_shipping_method(weight):

print(
    "The cheapest option available is $%.2f with %s shipping")
```

I kind of understand that the code goes on to define those as variables, but if someone could explain it to me a little more clearly? There hasn't been anything like the %.2f and %s so far in the lessons and I'd like to understand better how the lecturer came to those figures.

Edited to add: my solution is this below
Edited again, here's the entire page

```
    def ground_ship(weight):
  if weight >= 10:
    cost = 4.75
  elif weight >= 6:
    cost = 4
  elif weight >= 2:
    cost = 3
  elif weight >= 0:
    cost = 1.50  
  print(weight * cost + 20)

premium_ship = 125

def drone_ship(weight):
  if weight >= 10:
    cost = 14.25
  elif weight >= 6:
    cost = 12
  elif weight >= 2:
    cost = 9
  elif weight >= 0:
    cost = 4.5
  print(weight * cost)

ground_ship(10)
drone_ship(1.5)

def best_deal(weight):
  if ground_ship < drone_ship and ground_ship < drone:
    method = "standard ground"
    cost = ground_ship
  elif premium_ship < drone_ship and premium_ship < ground_ship:
    method = "premium"
    cost = premium_ship
  else:
    method = "drone"
    cost = drone_ship

    print("The cheapest option for your package is " + method + " shipping and the cost will be $" + str(cost))

best_deal(10)
```

Everything checks without an error until I tried to print with best_deal(10) which then returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 41, in <module>
    best_deal(10)
  File "script.py", line 29, in best_deal
    if ground_ship < drone_ship and ground_ship < drone:
TypeError: unorderable types: function() < function()
```

Disregard the line # this code starts on line 28

Comment: What is `ground_ship`? Looks like a function but you don't provide that code. Also the `%s` is string formatting (primarily used in python2.7). Modern string formatting uses `f"the val is {my_var}"` or `"the val is {}".format(my_var)`. (Though some developers still us `%` notation).

Comment: Try this: if ground_ship < drone_ship < drone    Also fix the elif line like this.

Comment: I should provide the whole code, that might help!

Comment: Also ground_ship < drone_ship < drone that actually found a different error because it should be ground_ship < drone_ship < premium_ship but I'm still getting the same error changing the notation on that and the elif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You comparison statement is effectively comparing functions, hence the error. What you intended to do is compare *the result* of each function calculations. For that, you would need to change a little each function, so that they return the calculated cost. Printing it is not enough. So, with that in mind, here what a working version of the code looks like. I'll add comments in a moment.

```
def print_cheapest_shipping_method(weight):
  print("The cheapest option available is $%.2f with %s shipping")

def ground_ship(weight):
  if weight >= 10:
    cost = 4.75
  elif weight >= 6:
    cost = 4
  elif weight >= 2:
    cost = 3
  elif weight >= 0:
    cost = 1.50
  total_cost = weight * cost + 20
  print(total_cost)
  return(total_cost)  # have the function return the calculated value

premium_ship = 125

def drone_ship(weight):
  if weight >= 10:
    cost = 14.25
  elif weight >= 6:
    cost = 12
  elif weight >= 2:
    cost = 9
  elif weight >= 0:
    cost = 4.5
  total_cost = weight * cost
  print(total_cost)
  return(total_cost)  # have the function return the calculated value

ground_ship(10)
drone_ship(1.5)

def best_deal(weight):
  # now you can compare values, by calling each function with the given 'weight'
  if ground_ship(weight) < drone_ship(weight) and ground_ship(weight) < premium_ship:
    method = "standard ground"
    cost = ground_ship(weight)  # get the cost from the function calculation

  elif premium_ship < drone_ship(weight) and premium_ship < ground_ship(weight):
    method = "premium"
    cost = premium_ship  # in this case, premium_ship is a value
  else:
    method = "drone"
    cost = drone_ship(weight)  # get the cost from the function calculation

  print("The cheapest option for your package is " + method + " shipping and the cost will be $" + str(cost))

best_deal(10)
```

Also see it in action here: https://eval.in/1116417

Comment: Ok that was really helpful- I was able to use this to fix my own code and also I understand what was incorrect which is thank you exactly what I needed.